# Navigation bar IE7 woes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My navigation bar is a tragic mess when displayed in IE7.  I'm a touch new to this legacy coding and from what I've read there are issues with pseudo states, z indexes and absolute position besides a few others.

I've tried various things to try and get it to react properly but no joy.

I've also tried using

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

as I was under the impression that would help but the issue remains.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<aside>
    <div class="module blue">
        <h2 class="wtf">Index<a href="../index.php">Select</a></h2>
        <br/>
        <h2 class="wtf">Admin Home<a href="../admin.php">Select</a></h2>
    </div>
</aside>
```

the css:

```
aside { display: block; }

h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    position: relative;
}

aside {
    padding-top:10px;
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    min-width:250px;
}

.navMenu{
    display:block;
    padding-top:10px;
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    min-width:250px;
}

.module {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.module h2 {
    background: #ccc;
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 25px 10px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.module h2 a {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0 10px;
        border-left: 5px solid white;
        -webkit-transition: padding 0.1s linear;
        -moz-transition: padding 0.1s linear;
        -ms-transition: padding 0.1s linear;
        -o-transition: padding 0.1s linear;
    }

    .module h2 a:hover {
        padding: 0 14px;
    }
    .module h2 a:active {
        padding: 0 16px;
    }

    .module h2 a:before,
    .module h2 a:after {
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    .module h2 a:before {
        left: -12px;
        border-top: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid white;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }

    .module.blue h2 a {
        background: #a2d6eb;
    }
    .module.blue h2 a:hover {
        background: #c5f0ff;
    }
    .module.blue h2 a:after {
        left: -5px;
        border-top: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid #a2d6eb;
        margin-top: -6px;
    }
    .module.blue h2 a:hover:after {
        border-right-color: #c5f0ff;
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the tragic mess looks like in IE7?

Comment: Um, The select boxes have dropped and are behind h2 names.  If I remove the relative from H2 it helps, removing float right from the A tag also helps but I can't make it perfect.

Comment: Re IE7.js -- Note that IE7.js is designed to make IE6 work like IE7. If you want to make IE7 work like IE8 or IE9, you need to use IE8.js or IE9.js, not IE7.js.

Comment: Also, if you're using HTML5 elements like `<aside>` then you must use htmlshiv.js or modernizr.js, otherwise IE8 and earlier will break (this is likely to be your main problem).

Comment: @Spudley - ....I have nothing to say. :)  Just a large thank you

Using a shiv.  I think i can 'hack' the menu using a negative margin top and removing relative.

Comment: Also, IE7 doesn't support the following: `:before`, `:after`, `transition`, `box-shadow`, `rgba()` colours....

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may help someone else.

In my example, the relative positioning on the H2 tag was causing havoc.

I worked through dev mode in IE until I was able to get the result I wasnted, popped the code into a new css file and used the IF IE conditionals to call that stylesheet.

It's not as nice as it is in later versions but it's a damn sight better :)

Thanks to all who helped